# Get penultimate HTML element by JS

Tags: javascript, html

For example, I have a chat.

```html
<div id="chat" style="transform: initial;" class="active selectable">
  <ul id="chat-messages" class="active">
    <li class="admin">
      <span>test1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="admin">
      <span>test2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="nick">[10136] someone: </span>
      <span>test3</span> 
    </li>
    <li>
</div>
```

And I need to get the penultimate element (test2).
How I can get it WITHOUT jQuery.

Comment: @Mohammad - Great to format the markup, but best not to correct the error in it (just in case it ends up being relevant, though it seems unlikely in this case). (Also, remove "thanks" and such when editing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of elements matching any CSS selector with [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Then you can take the `length - 2`th element:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#chat li");
var penultimate = list[list.length - 2];
```

Live Example:

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#chat li");
var penultimate = list[list.length - 2];
console.log(penultimate.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="chat" style="transform: initial;" class="active selectable">
  <ul id="chat-messages" class="active">
    <li class="admin"><span>test1
</span></li>
    <li class="admin"><span>test2
</span></li>
    <li><span class="nick">[10136] dimden: </span><span>test3</span>
    </li>
  </ul><!-- this was <li>, I fixed it -->
</div>
```

Comment: I realise you already know this, but for the sake of completion it's maybe worth adding in the option of `document.querySelector('#chat li:nth-last-child(2)')`.

Comment: Another question: If i'm trying to delete this element, I'm using:
`penultimate.removeChild(penultimate.lastChild);`
But it deletes only the message, and not deleting nickname.

Comment: @Eff: what exactly are you trying to do? If you can edit your question to include an explanation of your intent, and your requirements, then you'll (probably) get answers that accurately address the problem you're trying to solve. As it is `penultimate` only seems to have one child (`<span>test 2</span>`); so expecting it to remove the nickname (which appears to be the sibling *after* the `penultimate` node is counterintuitive. Although in this case, because you've got a `<li>` tag with no closing `</li>` at the end you're quite possibly not selecting the correct `<li>` anyway.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Good point. [`:nth-last-child`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#nth-last-child-pseudo) works for this example, yes, but it's so commonly misunderstood that I hesitate to point to it. :-)

Comment: @DavidThomas my bad that I didn't selected HTML correctly. I need to select penultimate message from chat and delete it from HTML. Code that I used is above.

Comment: @Effthecops - After the `var penultimate` line above, if you want to remove that `li`, you'd use `penultimate.parentNode.removeChild(penultimate)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined.
Code: 
`function removeMsg() {
  var list = document.querySelector('#chat li:nth-last-child(2)')
var penultimate = list[list.length - 2];
penultimate.parentNode.removeChild(penultimate)
  penultimate.removeChild(penultimate.lastChild);
}`

Comment: @Effthecops - David was suggesting an **alternative** to the code in the answer, not a correction. You'd use the code in the answer, not David's selector, **or** David's selector.